# Python: multiprocessing Pool with 2 functions

Tags: python, websocket, multiprocessing, pool

I have a problem with `multiprocessing.Pool()`.
My script connects to a websocket to get a bunch of data. This data is stored in a list.  My function `formula()` does calculations based on different desired scenarios and acts if a scenario returns True.
Down below I have posted a simplified code:

```
import multiprocessing, time, json

res_array = []

def process_message(msg):
   res_array.insert(0, msg)
   if len(res_array) > specificnumber:
            del res_array[specificnumber:]
            #inserts data in a list

def formula(res_array1):
    # handles list

def initiate():
    ma = SocketManager(client)
    conn_key = ma.start_multiplex_socket(listofsockets, process_message)
    ma.start()
    # starts websocket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=initiate())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p2', target=formula(res_array))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

As you can see, I have to call `initiate()` to start the websocket.
My plan was to get data from the websocket while formula is running simultaneously.

This code works perfectly but slowly. To fasten things up I wanted to try `multiprocessing.Pool()` but every example I found shows only one function used.

**Question:**
How can I assign 2 functions to one Pool? The pool should handle the function `initiate()` and `formula()` at the same time with `cpu_count()` as number of processes.
Is that possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can write a wrapper function for `initiate` and `formula`:

```
def intiate_formulate(res_array1):
    initiate()
    formula(res_array1)
```

And use that function

Comment: I've tried this but the script stops at `initiate()` I called the pool with `pool.map(intiate_formulate, res_array1)` sorry I'm not to experienced with multiprocessing